# Does Javadoc have an equivalent to <![CDATA[ ... ]]>?

Tags: java, html, xml, javadoc, cdata

Unfortunately, there is no CDATA in HTML.

This is a pity, because it would be perfect for adding `javadoc` comments that include XML, so you don't have to escape the < and >, for example:

```
/**<![CDATA[ This parses <complexType name=""> ]]>*/
```

However, it would be possible for `javadoc` to recognize the CDATA section, and convert it to HTML for you. For example:

```
This parses &lt;complexType name=""&gt;
```

Or it could use some simpler syntax than CDATA.  Because `javadoc` is extensible, it's possible someone has added this functionality; or maybe `javadoc` already has it buried somewhere inside... Does anybody know?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use JavaDoc's `@code` tag: `/** This parses {@code <complexType name="">} */`

Comment: +1

Note that {@code ... } can span multiple lines.  eclipse will claim it's an error, but it's not.  It also does brace-counting!  So you can use curlies in your actual code snippet, as long as they match up.

Comment: I'm seeing IDEA process a multi-line `{@code}` block by folding the lines together, which one won't suffer with `<pre>`. That's sad, as `{@code}` sounded like a nice solution to not having to escape the opening carets.

Answer (score 34):

Extending [@Fabian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1782088/505893), I use both `<pre>` and `{@code ...}`. Here an example with XML as source code:

```
/*Outputs data from a result set to an XML
 * with following structure:
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 * <row>
 *  <FIELD1>gregh</FIELD1>
 *  <FIELD2>487</FIELD2>
 *  <!-- etc. -->
 * </row>
 * <!-- more rows-->
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
```

`<pre>` allows you to write code on multiple lines and preserve its structure.

Tested with Eclipse 3.6.1.

Answer (score 9):

Close and reopen the `{@code}` tag around the braces to get ${dollar_sign_variables} to render correctly in eclipse despite [bug 206319](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=206319) and [bug 206345](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=206345) and without resorting to full HTML escaping:

```java
/*
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 * <outer>
 *   <inner1>Text</inner1>
 *   <inner2>$}{ "script" }{@code </inner2>
 * </outer>
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
```

which renders in Eclipse Indigo SR2 (3.7.2) as

```xml
<outer>
  <inner1>Text</inner1>
  <inner2>${ "script" }</inner2>
</outer>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have tried quite a few solutions, none of which were very satisfactory for my needs. Doing the pre + @code (or @literal) tags will usually work:

```
 <pre>
 {@literal
 <configFiles>
   <configFile>
     <type>LOGICAL_INDEX_CONFIG</type>
   </configFile>
 </configFiles>}
 </pre>
```

The trouble is, what if you have ${dollar_sign_variables} in your html? (and this is frequent if your documentation uses xml examples which rely on maven filtering). Say you have ${ITEM_INDEX_TO_LOGICAL}, Eclipse will render it like this:

```
<configFiles>
  <configFile>
     ITEM_INDEX_TO_LOGICAL

   }
```

Ultimately, I had no choice but to stick to the html-escaping method (you can use [this one](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/htmlencode/encode.aspx)) to get it to render propertly:

This:

```
 &lt;configFiles&gt;
   &lt;configFile&gt;
     &lt;type&gt;${ITEM_INDEX_TO_LOGICAL}&lt;/type&gt;
   &lt;/configFile&gt;
 &lt;/configFiles&gt;
```

Renders like this:

```
 </configFiles>
   <configFile>
     <type>${ITEM_INDEX_TO_LOGICAL}</type>
   </configFile>
 </configFiles>
```

This will unfortunately put you into a position where you can't really understand the 'example xml' being documented unless you render the Javadoc. Fortunately eclipse can do this for you on the fly...