# Putting sample XML code in Javadoc

Tags: java, xml, escaping, javadoc

How to put a sample XML code in Javadoc? The XML code includes angle brackets which I do not want to be processed.

I tried combinations of `PRE` and `code` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 27):

You can use `@code` javadoc tag. Take a look to [this post](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0623.html), wich contains some examples. Hope it helps

```
/**
 * To use this class use this XML   
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 * <xml>
 *   <parameter>foo</parameter>
 *   <value>bar</value>
 * </xml>
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to use HTML/XML encoding like `&lt;` for < and `&gt;` for >.

If you use Eclipse, there is a *Javadoc* view that shows you a preview.