# check style error when parsing javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle

I'm slowly trying to introduce checkStyle checks for javadocs in an existing code base.

It seems like every time it encounters  a parameter (@param or @return) which describes a list, map etc.. It fails to parse the code and throws an error, 
does anybody have any idea how to prevent this??

for example:

```
  /**
   * Process list of people.
   *
   * @param account the relevant account.
   * @return List<People> the people we are interested in.
   * @throws SQLException
   */
   private static List<People> getPeople(Account account) throws SQLException {}
```

so it cannot parse

```
* @return List<People> the people we are interested in.
```

and creates the error:

```
error: Javadoc comment at column 18 has parse error. Missed HTML close tag 'People'. Sometimes it means that close tag missed for one of previous tags.
```

This happens when trying to apply different checks and this jdoc does/should pass the checks.

any help would be great :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Javadoc specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#return), `@return` does not include the type of the returned value. You simply add a description of what is returned after `@return`. If you want to include the type, it is part of the description and thus HTML characters such as `<` need to be escaped (`&gt;`). A better option would be something like:

```
@return {@link List} of {@link People}
```

(You cannot link to parameterized types, but should instead link to both the generic type and the parameter type).

Answer (score 2):

You should probably escape `<` and `>` so that it is not considered an XML tag, like `&lt;` and `&gt;`. See this question too [How can I use "<" and ">" in javadoc without formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898897/how-can-i-use-and-in-javadoc-without-formating)

Comment: yep,but the problem is I do not want this comment to be considered as HTML. ideally I don't want to change the code ( which is valid ) , I want to adjust the checkstyle configuration (somehow) to allow this. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: This is not a valid Javadoc, I believe. So you will have to disable the Javadoc checks in checkstyle completely.

Comment: Ok, Your right :) :( . I think the solution is "* \@return \@code List<People> the people we are interested in."  Doesn't look good tho (clean code style).