# Check for improper angle bracket usage (not in tags) in inline Javadoc in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tags, javadoc

Pretty simple question: I often forget that using the less than and greater than symbols in Javadoc [doesn't work without using the either a literal block or `&lt;`/`&gt;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898897/how-can-i-use-and-in-javadoc-without-formatting), since they're treated as formatting tags. This subsequently causes my Jitpack build to fail. I use IntelliJ IDEA as my main Java IDE, which appears to give no warning when I use angle brackets in JavaDoc; **Is there a way to check against improper usage of these symbols?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to Serge Baranov from JetBrain's support team](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000799910/comments/115000657464):

> It's a known limitation, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-165488.

The issue's description reads as expected:

> Idea's 'HTML problems in Javadoc (DocLint)' does not report any
>   problems in the following javadoc:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * a < b > c
>  */
> void test();
> ```
>
> However, javadoc generation will fail in this case:
>
> ```
> Test.java:5: error: malformed HTML
>      * a < b > c
>          ^
> Test.java:5: error: bad use of '>'
>      * a < b > c
>              ^
> ```
>
> Usually this problem is noticed only at the javadoc generation phase
>   of Maven build process and that's rather inconvenient.
>
> Also, it would be great to have an intention to escape such symbols in
>   javadoc as &gt / &lt.

However, as of this posting, the bug has no special priority, spent time, or verification (though it has been triaged.) Developer/SO user [Roman Shevchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/378782/roman-shevchenko) appears to be assigned to the issue. I wouldn't expect a fix any time particularly soon, given this isn't exactly a huge issue.