# Disabling javadoc formatting for > <

Tags: java, maven, formatting, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

OK, all of the recommendations in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898897/how-can-i-use-and-in-javadoc-without-formatting) thread work but are not very readable in the code files. Is there a way to disable the default javadoc formatting and just write `x>1` with no problem?

Comment: That link *lists* all possibilities. You are in essence asking the very same question again, and there is no point in doing so. If *human readability* is your main focus, then pull in a framework that supports **markdown** in javadoc, and go with that.

Comment: I asked this question because none of the listed recommendations work for me.

Comment: I got that. But why do you expect that the answers you would here would be any different. The IT business is about balancing *your* preferences with what technology has to offer. Sometimes you simply give in. You agree with your team mates what format you want, and then everybody follows that. And in a few weeks, everybody is used to it. And as said: when human readable javadoc is so important to you, then include a mark down processor.

Comment: Yeah, actually my team does not agree on any of these formats, so there you have it.. I hoped that maybe there would be a different way.

Answer (score 1):

i guess javadoc's main goal is to make the customer of classes, methods, functions and procedures to not look into the source file.

So i suggest to use `&lt;` for < and `&gt;` for >, as the accepted answer of your related post tells to.