# Prevent Eclipse from converting @ character in <pre> javadoc tags to &#64;

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Javadoc comments for one of my package (`package-info.java`) that basically looks like this:

```
/**
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 * // Some comments...
 * final Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<>(0);
 * }
 * </pre>
 * 
 */
package com.holt.mypackage;
```

I also have enabled *Save Actions* with a *Format all lines* in the project properties. Each time I save the file, Eclipse replace `{@code` with:

```
* {
*   &#64;code
```

...completely breaking my Javadoc.

I tried using `<pre>` and `<code>` manually, but then the Maven javadoc plugin complains about invalid characters `<` and `>` in HTML (due to `Foo<>`). If I disable *Save Actions*, everything works well from Eclipse to Maven.

Is there a way to tell Eclipse not to replace such characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=552012) you have to "turn of the *Format Java code snippets inside 'pre' tag* setting":

1. `Window > Preferences`
2. `Java > Code Style > Formatter`
3. If you do not have a custom profile click on `New...`
4. `Edit...`
5. `Comments` > Uncheck *Format Java code snippets ...*

As a result Eclipse IDE won't format the content of `<pre>` tags anymore.

If you still want to benefit from formatting I advise you to use the `<code>` tag. You just have to escape the `<>` characters properly as shown below:

```java
/**
 * <pre>
 * <code>
 * // Some comments...
 * final Foo&lt;Integer&gt; foo = new Foo&lt;&gt;(0);
 * }
 * </code>
 * </pre> 
 *
 */
package com.holt.mypackage;
```

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898897/how-can-i-use-and-in-javadoc-without-formatting/6049713).