# How to use angle brackets in javadoc? For example to include <br>, MyClass<String> into javadoc text

Tags: java, javadoc

I cannot add into javadoc (method help/API description) text like:

```
...this method returns html-formatted text with HTML-line-breaks (adds <br> tags)...
```

but **`<br>`** disappears because angle brackets are not allowed.

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898897/how-can-i-use-and-in-javadoc-without-formatting)

Comment: [How can I use “<” and “>” in javadoc without formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2898897), [Does Javadoc have an equivalent to <![CDATA[ … \]\]>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1782040)